# Register instance of a type to ServiceCollection in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using Asp.Net Core 2.2 and I want to register an instance of a type to the base type.

And in the Startup file I'm trying to Register type and instance as follow:

```
foreach (var type in typesFromAssemblies)
        {
            var settings = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
            {
                if (!prop.CanRead || !prop.CanWrite)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var key = type.Name + "." + prop.Name;

                // load instance from database
                var setting = GetSettingByKey<string>(provider, key, loadSharedValueIfNotFound: true);

                if (setting == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                object value = CommonHelper.GetMovCustomTypeConverter(prop.PropertyType)
                    .ConvertFromInvariantString(setting);

                // set property
                prop.SetValue(settings, value, null);
            }

            // how I can set "settings" in services?
            // services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(settings.GetType(), settings, lifetime));
        }
```

How I can set "settings" instance to the services?

Comment: Your code looks like you want to solve a strange problem. I know my comment is useless to find a solution, but could you explain what problem you are trying to solve, and why you have DI config in a database?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Using different registration and implementation types is already available, that's how you can register interfaces using concrete implementation types. You can register any type, not just an interface. This code doesn't explain what you want to do

Comment: As for the word `setting` repeated in the code, that's the job of the [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) subsystem. You can combine Configuration and DI through the [Option pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to register configuration classes that will be injected when a type is created by DI. That's why you see those `IOption<TConfig>` parameters in various services.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, 
I have more than one thousand settings with default value in the application and I need user can be changing in the management panel.
I saved settings in the database and I want to load in the startup and map to the specific type and load as DI. @PanagiotisKanavos